# MAUI: Listview cannot be refreshed automatically

Tags: maui

There are 2 elements binding data in my test app, one is Button, another is Listview. But Listview cannnot be refreshed automatically. But if I disable `ButtonText = $"It took {totalSecs} seconds"` in ViewModel, Listview can be refreshed automatically. Any ideas? TIA.

Here is the Xaml file.

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
         x:Class="test.MainPage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:PurchasesInvoiceMasterViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout 
        Spacing="25" 
        Padding="30,0" 
        VerticalOptions="Start">

        <Button 
            x:Name="PurchasesInvoiceList"
            Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
            Command="{Binding AddListCommand}"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Get Purchases Invoice List"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <ListView x:Name="PurchasesInvoiceMasterObjectView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding PurchasesInvoiceMasterObject}" 
            HeightRequest="500">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding purchases_invoice_id}"
                              Detail="{Binding purchases_invoice_date }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is ViewModel.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace test
{
    class PurchasesInvoiceMasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ICommand AddListCommand { get; set; }

        private string _buttonText = "Purchases Invoice List";
        public string ButtonText
        {
            get => _buttonText;
            set
            {
                if (_buttonText != value)
                {
                    _buttonText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("");
                }
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<PurchasesInvoiceMaster> _purchasesInvoiceMasterObject = new();
        public ObservableCollection<PurchasesInvoiceMaster> PurchasesInvoiceMasterObject 
        {
            get => _purchasesInvoiceMasterObject;
            set
            {
                if (_purchasesInvoiceMasterObject != value)
                {
                    _purchasesInvoiceMasterObject = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("");
                }
            }
        }

        public PurchasesInvoiceMasterViewModel()
        {
            AddListCommand = new Command(() => 
            {
                double statrtSecs = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
                string purchasesInvoiceMaster = "test.PurchasesInvoiceMaster.xml";
                using (Stream streamPurchasesInvoiceMaster = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(purchasesInvoiceMaster))
                {
                    using (var readerPurchasesInvoiceMaster = new System.IO.StreamReader(streamPurchasesInvoiceMaster))
                    {
                        var xmlpurchasesInvoiceMaster = XDocument.Load(readerPurchasesInvoiceMaster);
                        foreach (XElement xmmd in xmlpurchasesInvoiceMaster.Descendants("curtemp01"))
                        {
                            _purchasesInvoiceMasterObject.Add(new PurchasesInvoiceMaster
                            {
                                purchases_invoice_id = xmmd.Element("purchases_invoice_id").Value,
                                purchases_invoice_date = xmmd.Element("purchases_invoice_date").Value,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                double endSecs = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
                float totalSecs = (float)(endSecs - statrtSecs);
                ButtonText = $"It took {totalSecs} seconds";
            }); 
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") 
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to explain this better - I have no idea what you mean by "refresh automatically".  Are you saying the UI does not refresh as properties of the objects change?

Comment: Yes, button text changed but listview not.

Comment: if remove ButtonText = $"It took {totalSecs} seconds", listview will be changed.

Comment: if keep ButtonText = $"It took {totalSecs} seconds" but remove Binding ButtonText, listview works fine as well.

Comment: Could please provide the xml file? I tried to create a sample to reproduce the issue but it needed the xml file.

Comment: Don't worry about xml file. Simply do:  _purchasesInvoiceMasterObject.Add(new PurchasesInvoiceMaster
                {
                    purchases_invoice_id = "purchases_invoice_id",
                    purchases_invoice_date = "purchases_invoice_date"
                });

Comment: I have tried this and the listview and the button's text both updated when I clicked it.

Comment: I have tested on Samsung SM-A225F (Android 11.0 - API30) and the listview is not working.

Comment: Did you try to add the data by the code `_purchasesInvoiceMasterObject.Add(new PurchasesInvoiceMaster { purchases_invoice_id = "purchases_invoice_id", purchases_invoice_date = "purchases_invoice_date" })` not read the xml file?

Comment: Yes, added data via code as well.

Comment: I tested it on the simulator android 12 and it worked well.